# Ajax in AspNetMvc error request

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i have simple page:

```
<div style="width:600px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">
    <div style="background-color: lightgray">
        <h2>My Products</h2>
    </div>
    <p>Click the button to Get Products with an Ajax call</p>

    <input id="btnAjax" name="btnAjax" type="button" value="Get Products" />
    <div id="products" style="background-color:lightskyblue">
        <div id='loadingmessage' style='display:none'>
            loading...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and section Script:

```
@section Scripts {
        @*@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")*@
    <script>
        $('#btnAjax').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Test/GetProducts',
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                data: { id: 1 },
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'html'
            })     
            .success(function (result) {
                $('#products').html(result);
                $('#loadingmessage').hide();
            })
            .error(function (xhr, status, throwError) {
                alert(status);
            })           
        });
        </script>
    }
```

method in TestController names GetProducts(int id):

```
    public PartialViewResult GetProducts(int id)
    {
        var listOfCourses = db.Courses.ToList();
        Task.Delay(9000000);
        if(id == 1)  
            throw new Exception("something bad");

        return PartialView("_GetProducts", listOfCourses);
    }
```

Is any way to set 'id' in button (#btnAjax) and throw it to ajax script? for example:

```
<input id="btnAjax" name="btnAjax" type="button" value="Get Products" data:id="1" />
```

and then read it in ajax script

```
data: { id: $(this).id
```

??

The second question is how I can get message error from exception in error event ("something bad")

Comment: "The second question is how I can get message error from exception in error event ("something bad")" I'm not understanding this question, sorry.

Comment: in error event:
 .error(function (xhr, status, throwError) {
HERE
}
and how HERE can i put alert with exception message from method GetProducts(int id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it as a data attribute e.g. `data-id`:

`<input id="btnAjax" name="btnAjax" type="button" value="Get Products" data-id="1" />`

and to read it you can use either of these:

`$("input#btnAjax").attr("data-id")`

`$("input#btnAjax").data("id")`

The second option is the most up to date way of doing this.

EDIT:

For your second question, you need to return JSON e.g.

```
public ActionResult GetProducts(int id)
{
    var listOfCourses = db.Courses.ToList();

    Task.Delay(9000000);

    if (id == 1)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        return Json(new { ErrorMessage = "Test" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    return PartialView("_GetProducts", listOfCourses);
}
```

I think the above should work (I haven't had a chance to try this myself). By setting the status code to an error code (and not 200 STATUS OK), you should hit the `error` function in the AJAX code in your JavaScript.

I'm not 100% sure about this bit, but certainly my first part of my answer should work for you.

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' to 'System.Web.Mvc.PartialViewResult'

Comment: Check my code, I'm using `public ActionResult.....` in the method signature. That means you can pass either `JSON` or `PartialViewResult`.

Comment: thanks you for help :-) The experience is most worth at the world :-)!